# Export information of buffer from QGIS to stata

Tags: qgis, export, buffer, stata

I want to create buffers around the centroids of US-counties (in QGIS) and I'd like to export the information regarding the centroids and the buffers to stata. Is there an easy way?

I haven't worked with geographic data so far.

Comment: I am not sure what strata is but maybe I can help you. What data do you want to export exactly? Is your data stored in the attribute table of your centroid points? If you have your data stored in the US-countries-centroids, you can use the tool "buffer" to create buffers around those points. Then your data is automatically stored in the new buffer polygon layer. I just googled stata. I hope i found the tool that you are using. It seems that you can import shapefiles to stata. In QGIS you right click on your layer in the content table and then you can export it. Is that what you mean? I'm not s

Comment: @Paula_123 Stata is a statistic software widely used in the field of economics. The overall goal of this task is to set buffer zones with different distances and to create a variable that indicates whether another county is within the buffer zone Thx for the quick response!